# $f(w)+g(w)<x \implies r+s<x$ - homework

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have a question that says

> Show of real functions $f$ and $g$ that $f(\omega)+g(\omega)<x$ if and only if there exist rationals $r$ and $s$ such that $r+s<x$, $f(\omega)<r$, and $g(\omega)<s$.

I went about this by rewriting the inequality like
$f(\omega)<x-g(\omega)$ and $g(\omega)<x-f(\omega)$, and then arguing from there that because of the density of rational numbers in $\mathbf{R}$, there exist rationals $r$ and $s$ such that

$f(\omega)<r<x-g(\omega)$

$g(\omega)<s<x-f(\omega)$.

However, I don't know how to get $r+s<x$. I tried adding my inequalities, but I don't see the way of getting the result I want. Any ideas?

Comment: First choose some positive real $t$ such that $f(\omega)+g(\omega)+2t<x$ then some rational $r$ in $(f(\omega),f(\omega)+t)$ and some rational $s$ in $(g(\omega),g(\omega)+t)$.

Comment: @Did: Post as an answer, that does the trick. Thanks!